# Declaration of an object in another header file

Tags: c++, object, declaration

)
I have a problem that could be quite simple to solve but I cannot find the right formalism in c++.
I want to declare an object of another class the given header file. Unfortunately I get the error:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for     C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp: In constructor
‘new_raphs::new_raphs(Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd)’:
calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp:7:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘stiff_nonl::stiff_nonl()’
:set_force(node_matrix,dof_matrix_input)
^
calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp:7:44: note: candidates are:
In file included from calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.h:8:0,
from calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp:1:
calc/solver_nonl/../fem_nonl/stiff_nonl.h:20:5: note: stiff_nonl::stiff_nonl(Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::MatrixXd)
stiff_nonl(MatrixXd node_matrix, MatrixXd dof_matrix_input, MatrixXd element_matrix, MatrixXd element_info_matrix);
^
calc/solver_nonl/../fem_nonl/stiff_nonl.h:20:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
calc/solver_nonl/../fem_nonl/stiff_nonl.h:17:7: note: 
stiff_nonl::stiff_nonl(const stiff_nonl&)
class stiff_nonl : public set_force
^
calc/solver_nonl/../fem_nonl/stiff_nonl.h:17:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp: In member function ‘Eigen::MatrixXd& new_raphs::get_epsilon_results(int, int)’:
calc/solver_nonl/new_raphs.cpp:92:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Fehler 1
```

I have declared objects of different classes often before but what am I doing wrong here?

The header file looks as follows:

```
#ifndef NEW_RAPHS_H
#define NEW_RAPHS_H
# include "../../pre/boundary_force/set_force.h"
# include <iostream>
#include "../fem_lin/stiff.h"
#include "../fem_nonl/stiff_nonl.h"
using namespace std;
class new_raphs : set_force
{
public:
new_raphs(MatrixXd node_matrix, MatrixXd dof_matrix_input, MatrixXd element_matrix, MatrixXd element_info_matrix, MatrixXd force_matrix_input);
MatrixXd elements;
MatrixXd elements_info;
MatrixXd force_matrix;
void calc();
VectorXd U;
MatrixXd res;
MatrixXd result_matrix;
MatrixXd &get_result();
stiff_nonl stiffness_nonl;   // here is the bug!
MatrixXd &get_epsilon_results(int noe, int num_gauss_point);
};
#endif // NEW_RAPHS_H
```

He obviousely doesnt like the declaration stiff_nonl stiffness_nonl; ???
Does it have something to do that the stiff_nonl class inherits from another class???? Do I have to consider this in the declaration?

Hope one of the c++ checkers can help me here?

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers Franz

Comment: Giving `stiff_nonl ` a default constructor(with no args) or the correct arguments will probably solve your problem. NOTE:  it's common practice to captialise the first character of each word when naming a type, `stiff_nonl ` should probably be `Stiff_Nonl `.

Comment: Probably adding stiffness_nonl to the initialization list of the constructor of new_raphs will help (slightly different solution to the problem as shown by George)

Answer (score 0):

stiff_nonl does not have a default constructor. You can pass correct arguments in new_raphs constructor initialization list, e.g:

```
new_raphs::new_raphs(MatrixXd node_matrix, MatrixXd dof_matrix_input, MatrixXd element_matrix, MatrixXd element_info_matrix, MatrixXd force_matrix_input)
    : stiffness_nonl() //pass arguments to stiff_nonl constr. inside brackets
{
    //...
}
```

Also I believe that you wanted public inheritance here:

```
class new_raphs : public set_force
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow thank you! Now it works :)

The correct constructor was:

```
new_raphs::new_raphs(MatrixXd node_matrix, MatrixXd dof_matrix_input, MatrixXd element_matrix, MatrixXd element_info_matrix, MatrixXd force_matrix_input)

:set_force(node_matrix,dof_matrix_input), stiffness_nonl(node_matrix, dof_matrix_input, element_matrix, element_info_matrix)
```

I am still a little bit confused why the object name (stiffness_nonl) and not the class or constructor name (stiff_nonl)??? This is a little bit weird to me...

Cheers Franz

Comment: You need to read c++/object oriented programming book. In first case you are passing arguments to base class (set_force), the second is initialization of the class field (stiffness_nonl). Read what's the difference between class and object (instance of the class), also learn more about inheritance.